# Add country holidays to prophet model when using lists

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I wish to add US holidays to my data for modelling using the Facebook prophet function.

I can add a predefined list of holidays i.e. NFL playoff and Super Bowl dates at model fitting time but it appears that country holidays need to be fit prior to model fitting.

From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#built-in-country-holidays) it shows that the country holidays are added to the prophet object and then fitted but I am unsure how to do this when using map as a data object (.x) needs to be specified when using map

How can I add US holidays to my model using a list of data frames?

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
#install.packages("pacman")
#library(pacman)

# LOAD LIBRARIES
pacman::p_load(tidyquant,tidyverse,prophet,purrr)

# SPECIFY STOCKS TO PULL
tickers = c("AAPL","AMZN")

# GET STOCK PRICE INFO
getSymbols(tickers, 
           from = '2013-01-01',
           to = '2016-06-30',
           warnings = FALSE,
           auto.assign = TRUE)

# MAP DATAFRAMES TO A LIST
dfList <- mget(tickers) %>%
  map(~ fortify.zoo(.x) %>% 
        select(1,5) %>% 
  rename(ds = 1,
         y = 2))

# SPECIFY NFL IMPORTANT DATES
playoffs <- tibble(
  holiday = 'playoff',
  ds = as.Date(c('2008-01-13', '2009-01-03', '2010-01-16',
                 '2010-01-24', '2010-02-07', '2011-01-08',
                 '2013-01-12', '2014-01-12', '2014-01-19',
                 '2014-02-02', '2015-01-11', '2016-01-17',
                 '2016-01-24', '2016-02-07')),
  lower_window = 0,
  upper_window = 1
)
superbowls <- tibble(
  holiday = 'superbowl',
  ds = as.Date(c('2010-02-07','2011-02-06','2012-02-05','2013-02-03','2014-02-02','2015-02-01','2016-02-07','2017-02-05','2018-02-04','2019-02-03','2020-02-02')),
  lower_window = 0,
  upper_window = 1
)

holidays <- bind_rows(playoffs, superbowls) %>% 
  filter(ds >= min(dfList$AAPL$ds) & ds <= max(dfList$AAPL$ds))

# CALL THE PROPHET FUNCTION TO FIT THE MODEL
model_list <- map(dfList,
                  prophet, 
                  holidays = holidays)

# TAKES THE MODEL ABOVE AND THE SPECIFIED FORECAST PERIOD TO PRODUCE A SUITABLE 
# DATA FRAME
future_list <- map(model_list,
                   make_future_dataframe,
                   periods = 365)

# USE THE GENERIC PREDICT FUNCTION TO GET OUR FORECAST
forecast_list <- map2(model_list,
                      future_list,
                      predict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the anonymous function call (`function(x)` shortform is `~`)

```
model_list <- map(dfList,
                ~  {
               m <- prophet(holidays = holidays)
               m <- add_country_holidays(m, country_name = 'US')
               m <- fit.prophet(m, .x)
               return(m)
              })
```

and once we get the prediction, can check the components

```
pdf("plottesting.pdf") 
p1 <- map2(model_list, forecast_list, prophet_plot_components)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: If I wanted to plot the changepoints using the map/map2 syntax how could I do this? The syntax for this is plot(m, forecast) + add_changepoints_to_plot(m) which I have tried with a combination of map and map2: p2 <- map2(model_list, forecast_list, plot) + map(model_list, add_changepoints_to_plot)

Comment: @TheGoat  Perhaps, `map2(model_list, forecast_list, ~ plot(.x, .y) + add_changepoints_to_plot(.x))`  Here `.x` is the first list element and `.y` is the second.  Based on your syntax.  I assume `m` as the model component and forecast as the `forecast_list` element

Comment: this worked perfectly, now to figure out how to plot the ggplot object from a list ;)

Comment: @TheGoat You can use the same strategy by looping over both lists, extract the components with anonymous function `.x` and `.y` if it is `map2` or just `.x` in `map`.

Comment: thanks for your help. Since p2 <- map2(model_list, forecast_list, ~ plot(.x, .y) + add_changepoints_to_plot(.x)) contained a ggplot object I used a simple map(p2,print) to plot the objects. Cheers for your help.